# Running `grunt` on VM Shared Directory

Tags: javascript, windows, gruntjs, vagrant

Using Vagrant with a Windows host and Linux guest, `grunt` returned the following error when trying to run a job.

As I understand, this file path exceeds the 255 character limit of Windows when on a host-guest shared directory.

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open '/u01/aa/bb/build/share/app-core/app-
ui/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-
wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-
data/node_modules/combined-stream/test/integration/test-delayed-streams-and-buffers-
and-strings.js'
```

I could develop on a non-shared directory on my guest VM, but I'd prefer to use a shared directory since I use an IDE on the host.

How can I fix this issue so that I can run `grunt` on the shared directory?

Answer (score 5):

I experienced a similar issue while running yeoman with angular-generator. The solution I found right now is a little trick leveraging the way npm handles it's dependencies and [folder structure](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html).

Please consider that the problem you are experiencing is probably only affecting a few files (and probably only the imagemin module).

For Yeoman my solution was to first generate, skipping the automatically started installation:

```
yo angular appname --skip-install
```

Starting bower installation manually:

```
bower install
```

Starting from here it should be interesting to you: Install "request" npm module as first level module (instead of a depencdency deeply resolved inside imagemin later):

```
npm install request --save-dev
```

So if you now run the regular npm install to fetch the remaining modules, the already existing request module is used.

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

Please note that using `--no-bin-links` is also a good idea if you don't want to run VirtualBox [as an Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232778/nodejs-npm-installing-modules-on-ntfs-partition).

So, to answer your question. Running grunt should work if you correctly setup your packages and call npm install before. The module "request" is an arbitrary module that prevents the big path of the `test-delayed-streams-and-buffers-and-strings.js` file.

Comment: great answer, fixes the same issue with `yo ember`

Comment: glad it works for other use cases as well! unfortunatelly i got neither the setup bounty (vote equality) nor an accepted answer for this one. well, happens.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the default `vboxsf` synced folder type, you may consider using the new rsync based synced folder to work around the issue.

`rsync` type will monitor the folders between host and guest, copy files directories to keep them in sync.

The difference between default `vboxsf` and `rsync` is that the latter will cause the guest Linux to run the application (grunt in your case) from its native file system (e.g. `ext4`) instead of `vboxsf` (provided by VirtualBox Guest Additions, after all the files are on Windows).

`rsync` synced folder basically make use of `rsync` CLI utility to copy / sync files and directories between hosts. So there are 2 copies of everything. When you run your `grunt` against the file system within the guest, it is native Linux file system and should not be affected by long path (but ext4 does have a max **filename** length of 255 bytes).

By default, Vagrant only syncs the folders on `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload`. But you can run `vagrant rsync` to manually force sync or `vagrant rsync-auto` to monitor changes and sync in real time.

Reference: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html

You can set synced folder type to rsync in your `Vagrantfile` below

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync",
    rsync__exclude: ".git/"
end
```

Update

Tested creating the directory tree structure and a file, no problem opening it from a Linux perspective, the file system is ext4. I suspect this is a problem with npm.

```sh
terry@arch:/$ uname -a
Linux arch.apac.lab 3.14.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 14 20:40:47 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
terry@arch:/$ cat /u01/aa/bb/build/share/app-core/app-ui/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/test/integration/test-delayed-streams-and-buffers-and-strings.js
test
```

Update - rsync synced folder test

I did the previous test on a physical Linux installation. The following is on a quick test on Mac, guest is the same as above.

rsync synced folder configuration

```rb
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/u01/aa/bb/build/share/app-core/app-ui/           node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-   wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/        node_modules/combined-stream/test/integration", type: "rsync
```

> NOTE: I `chown -R vagrant:vagrant /u01/` recursively beforehand to avoid permission issues when syncing.

sync on `vagrant up`

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /ops/arch64/ => /u01/aa/bb/build/share/app-core/app-ui/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/test/integration
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /ops/arch64
==> default: VM already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use `--provision` to force it

$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Sun Apr 27 10:36:10 2014 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@archlinux:~$ cd /u01/aa/bb/build/share/app-core/app-ui/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/test/integration
vagrant@archlinux:/u01/aa/bb/build/share/app-core/app-ui/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/test/integration$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r----- 1 vagrant vagrant   14 Apr 27 10:35 test-delayed-streams-and-buffers-and-strings.js
-rw-r----- 1 vagrant vagrant 5018 Apr 27 10:22 Vagrantfile
vagrant@archlinux:/u01/aa/bb/build/share/app-core/app-ui/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/test/integration$ cat test-delayed-streams-and-buffers-and-strings.js
stackoverflow
```

Result is the same. As mentioned earlier, I suspect that this may be a npm issue.

Comment: so running with `rsync` should prevent the long path name issue since the `grunt` command will be running as if it's running on the guest's OS? if possible, could you please give a reference? I will try this out tomorrow morning - thanks.

Comment: this really confuses me - `When you run your grunt against the file system within the guest, it is native Linux file system and should not be affected by long path (but ext4 does have a max filename length of 255 bytes).` As I read it, the first sentence indicates that there's no length max, but then the second says that there is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. `test-delayed-streams-and-buffers-
and-strings.js` is the filename, `/u01/aa/bb/build/share/app-core/app-
ui/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-
wrapper/node_modules/download/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-
data/node_modules/combined-stream/test/integration/` is the path (of many dentries).

Comment: Yes, that's right. Also, Terry, thanks for your help, but I tried `rsync` for my synced folder, yet I still saw the same error.

Comment: I tested opening such a file with that full path, no problem from a Linux perspective, see the updated answer. I suspect this is a problem with npm.

Comment: But, your /u01/... is not a synced folder. Mine is. Your test would be similar to my environment if you made it a shared folder.

Comment: Updated answer, tested with vagrant rsync synced folder, result is the same.

Comment: rsync is a great idea, however the problem ist not the network sharing, but the actual path length on NTFS filesystems. If you try to create a file with the same path and name manually on Windows, this will fail as well. Thus, only changing the way files are transferred will not help.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed, continued help, Terry. When you say `result is the same`, it failed for you?

Comment: @KevinMeredith `result is the same` I mean rsync synced folder works fine (vagrant was able to create the directory structure and copy the files over) and within the VM I was able to open the file with its full path. Did you see Tarnschaf's comment? I think it makes sense as your host is Windows (using `vboxsf` synced folder type).

Comment: @TerryWang - are you on a Mac or Windows?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I did mention in the answer that the tests were done on Mac (maybe it wasn't bold enough ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For an actual solution to this, check out [this comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7228#issuecomment-82829637), or continue reading here:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["sharedfolder", "add", :id, "--name", "www", "--hostpath", (("//?/" + File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/www").gsub("/","\\"))]
end

config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mkdir /home/vagrant/www"
config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` www /home/vagrant/www", run: "always"
```

In the code above, I am appending \\?\ to the current directory absolute path. This will actually force the Windows API to allow an increase in the MAX_PATH variable (normally capped at 260). Read more about [max path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath). This is happening during the sharedfolder creation which is intentionally handled by VBoxManage and not Vagrant's "synced_folder" method. The last bit is pretty self-explanatory; we create the new shared folder and then make sure it's mounted each time the machine is accessed or touched since Vagrant likes to reload its mounts/shared folders on each load.

I hope this helps!