# npm install dependency order

Tags: node.js, npm

In my `package.json`, I have:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "download": "^0.1.18",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^0.11.3",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1"
}
```

When I run `npm install`, it tries to install `grunt-contrib-imagemin` before anything else and it throws an error.

The workaround is to `npm install download`, THEN `npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin` manually, then `npm install` the rest of the packages.

Why doesn't `npm install` respect the order of the packages listed in `devDependencies`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where `imagemin` fits in this exactly. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I made edits for clarity. Basically, if I try `npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin` it breaks. I need to `npm install download` first and then `grunt-contrib-imagemin` and it works fine. But with the config above, it doesn't install the deps in the order listed. It installs `grunt-contrib-imagemin` first for some reason.

Comment: npm doesn't respect the order because the order shouldn't matter at install time. If `npm install grunt-contrib-imagemin` ever fails you should file an issue with grunt-contrib-imagemin, it shouldn't need a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. For what it's worth, the issue is related to Windows 255 character filename limit. The only thing that works is installing a `grunt-contrib-imagemin` dependency first (`download`) to reduce filename length... http://stackoverflow.com/a/23323317/1308734