# Node.js npm: Can't install Babel-cli and Babel-core locally

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, permissions, babeljs

I'm trying to run `sudo npm install babel-cli babel-core --save-dev` in a clean project that had `npm init` already ran. I get errors saying that I have to run at root, but the install already is root. Here is the [npm-debug.log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xeau8mzn6t1ohx0/npm-debug.log?dl=0).

Comment: Seems like this is likely your issue since you are installing onto a flash drive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232778/nodejs-npm-installing-modules-on-ntfs-partition

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs + npm, installing modules on ntfs partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232778/nodejs-npm-installing-modules-on-ntfs-partition)