# Using mklink command with network drives

Tags: windows-7, symlink, mklink

I have two network drives that I access through Windows 7: `V:\` and `T:\` I am trying to create shortcuts between the two that alphabetise with folders (rather than files), so I am using the `mklink` command:

```
mklink /d \Photos V:\Photos
```

which creates a symlink at `C:\`.

I can move the symlink around locally. However, when I try to move the symlink to a network location, it begins copy the actual files over rather than symlinking them.

I figure that if I can create a symlink of a network drive on a local drive, what's stopping me creating a symlink of a network drive on another network drive. Am I correct in assuming this?

Is there any way to designate the destination file path when creating symlinks with the `mklink` command? Or is there any way to move symlinks to a network drive at all?

Answer (score 21):

If you need to make a directory junction (using /J) on a network drive, you can first creation a directory (/D) symbolic link and then create a junction off of that, like so:

```
mklink /D D:\shareLink \\network\share
mklink /J D:\junctionLink D:\shareLink
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked form me to move iTunes backup to a mapped drive! The only thing you need to do is to rename the "backup" directory in the AppData to something else, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working on Windows 10. I get "The file cannot be accessed by the system."

Answer (score 8):

You need to enable local to remote links by running this command with elevated rights:

```
fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation L2R:1
```

Also you can enable this with your local or group policy:
Computer\System\Filesystem\Selectively allow the evaluation of a symbolic link --> allow local to remote

Answer (score 2):

You will need to log onto the computer hosting the network drive and run the mklink command from there.

I recommend creating a junction `/J` instead of a symlinkd `/D`. Symlinks have some additional settings you need to be aware of. See [symbolic-link-cannot-be-followed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556247/195050).