# Are there any problems with this symlink traversal code for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, filesystems, symlink-traversal

In my efforts to resolve [Python issue 1578269](http://bugs.python.org/issue1578269), I've been working on trying to resolve the target of a symlink in a robust way. I started by using GetFinalPathNameByHandle as recommended [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221417/how-do-i-programmatically-access-the-target-path-of-a-windows-symbolic-link) and by [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364962%28VS.85%29.aspx), but it turns out that technique fails when the target is in use (such as with pagefile.sys).

So, I've written a new routine to accomplish this using CreateFile and DeviceIoControl (as it appears this is what Explorer does). The relevant code from [jaraco.windows.filesystem](https://svn.jaraco.com/jaraco/python/jaraco.windows/jaraco/windows/filesystem.py) is included below.

The question is, is there a better technique for reliably resolving symlinks in Windows? Can you identify any issues with this implementation?

```
 def relpath(path, start=os.path.curdir):
  """
  Like os.path.relpath, but actually honors the start path
  if supplied. See http://bugs.python.org/issue7195
  """
  return os.path.normpath(os.path.join(start, path))

 def trace_symlink_target(link):
  """
  Given a file that is known to be a symlink, trace it to its ultimate
  target.

  Raises TargetNotPresent when the target cannot be determined.
  Raises ValueError when the specified link is not a symlink.
  """

  if not is_symlink(link):
   raise ValueError("link must point to a symlink on the system")
  while is_symlink(link):
   orig = os.path.dirname(link)
   link = _trace_symlink_immediate_target(link)
   link = relpath(link, orig)
  return link

 def _trace_symlink_immediate_target(link):
  handle = CreateFile(
   link,
   0,
   FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
   None,
   OPEN_EXISTING,
   FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT|FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
   None,
   )

  res = DeviceIoControl(handle, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, None, 10240)

  bytes = create_string_buffer(res)
  p_rdb = cast(bytes, POINTER(REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER))
  rdb = p_rdb.contents
  if not rdb.tag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK:
   raise RuntimeError("Expected IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK, but got %d" % rdb.tag)
  return rdb.get_print_name()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't test with Vista until next week, but GetFinalPathNameByHandle should work, even for files in use - what's the problem you noticed?
In your code above, you forget to close the file handle.

Comment: Here's what fails for me. Make a link to pagefile.sys [cmd /c mklink pagefile2 pagefile.sys]. Then try to find the target of pagefile2. To call GetFinalPathNameByHandle (GFPNBH), you need a handle. If you use FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, GFPNBH will return "pagefile2". If you try to open without that flag, CreateFile returns an error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."