# How to retrieve the target of a Junction or Symlink with a standard user

Tags: c#, ntfs, resolve, junction, reparsepoint

I am trying to get the target of a junction in my program, but the only way I managed do it is:

1. Requesting Backup privileges
2. p-invoke CreateFile with special parameters to get a handle to the file/dir.
3. DeviceIoControl call to the get the target.

The 1st step will not work with normal user accounts, because they have no Backup privileges, and I don't want to get the UAC User Consent window every time I do this.

I think this is doable somehow, because a normal "dir /A:L" command resolves the target of the links.

Comment: There's a solution here at SO already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221417/how-do-i-programmatically-access-the-target-path-of-a-windows-symbolic-link

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately the GetFinalPathNameByHandle function needs a handle, and getting a handle on a folder needs that Backup privilege I mentioned. But, it is good to know about that API, I might need it later. So thank you for your answer.

Comment: My accepted answer was deleted by a moderator.  Not even converted to a comment, bizarre.  The blog post link: http://blog.kalmbach-software.de/2008/02/

Answer (score 0):

I think that this answer in stackoverflow would help you?
[How do I programmatically access the target path of a windows symbolic link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221417/how-do-i-programmatically-access-the-target-path-of-a-windows-symbolic-link)
It should be possible to include a reference to the function via DllImport Attribute in a c# program.

The required handle is obtainable from the a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.handle.aspx) instance. Somewhat funny that it is marked as obsolete, but maybe the warning states what else you can do.