# How to compare paths with "My Documents" and "Documents" in them?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm looking for files in `c:\users\taras\documents\<folder>` using Windows Search service (Provider=Search.CollatorDSO).
Output file path looks like this: `C:\Users\taras\My Documents\<folder>\<some_path>`. Now I need to get relative path , but first I have to normalize the path.

I tried do it like this:

```
string itemPath = new FileInfo(filePath).FullName;
string repoPath = new DirectoryInfo(repository).FullName;
```

But `itemPath` still have "My Documents" and `repoPath` still have "Documents".

Now I do it this way:

```
string itemPath = filePath.ToLower().Replace("\\my documents\\", "\\documents\\");
string repoPath = repository.ToLower().Replace("\\my documents\\", "\\documents\\");
```

It works but looks weird and doesn't help with similar other cases with Windows directories.

Is there any way to normalize the path (replace simlinks) before comparing?

Comment: http://blog.kalmbach-software.de/2008/02/

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21202/Reparse-Points-in-Vista

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - How to retreive the target of a Junction or Symlink with a standard user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240734/c-sharp-how-to-retreive-the-target-of-a-junction-or-symlink-with-a-standard-us)