# Windows API to fetch file attributes if path contains Symbolic link?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I used `_stat64(const char *path, struct __stat64 *buffer);` API to get the file/directory stats but this API fails if  input path contains a symbolic link.

`GetFileAttributes()` and `GetFileAttributesEx()` APIs too fail if file path contains a symbolic link. But as mentioned at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365682(v=vs.85).aspx), If the path points to a symbolic link, these two functions returns attributes for the symbolic link. Even `_stat64()` works if path points to symbolic link.

Is there any way to get the states/attribues of file/directory if path contains **[not points to]** a symbolic link ?

For instance - how to get attributes of "*test*" directory if input path is "D:\temp\**symbolic_link**\test"

**[Edit1]** 
Since eryksun's comment made sense. I tried GetFileAttributesEx() and _stat64() again. It worked but this time I had granted the full permissions to target directory and symbolic link both. It appeared to be permission issue. If I pass  "D:\temp\**symbolic_link**" then I get attributes/stats of symbolic link and if I pass "D:\temp\**symbolic_link**\test" then I get attributes/stats of test directory which is expected.

Comment: Which Windows version? `GetFileAttributes` traverses directory symbolic links for me in Windows 7.

Comment: @eryksun I am also on windows 7.  Did you pass D:\temp\symbolic_link\test or D:\temp\symbolic_link  to GetFileAttributes() ?  It fails for first path but works for second path.

Comment: I created a directory symbolic `mklink /d C:\Source\test\symbolic_link C:\Windows`, and then called `GetFileAttributesW(L"C:/Source/test/symbolic_link/System32")`.

Comment: @eryksun Did that work ? It doesn't at least in my system.

Comment: That's what I had tested (in both 32-bit and 64-bit) before making my initial comment. That it fails for you is puzzling since the kernel is making pretty much the same I/O and object manager calls that would parse the path and open the directory in other contexts. For example, I wouldn't expect you'd be able to create a file in the target directory.

Comment: Is the symbolic link actually working, e.g., can you say `dir d:\temp\symbolic_link\test` ?  Perhaps symbolic links are disabled on your computer, see what `fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation` says.

Comment: Why -1 ?IMO, it's valid question. I even have got an answer. Yes, Symbolic link is very much working and dir command clearly says that D:\temp\symbolic_link is of type <SYMLINKD>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the MSDN pages say anything related to your issue, but you may want to obtain the real path of your file by doing something like this:

```
void realpath(const char *filename, wchar_t *pathbuf, int size)
{
    OFSTRUCT of;
    HANDLE file = (HANDLE)OpenFile(filename,&of,OF_READ);
    GetFinalPathNameByHandle(file,pathbuf,size,FILE_NAME_OPENED);
    CloseHandle(file);
}
```

This will fill pathbuf with the reparsed path name of your file (up to the length of size).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Geza. Even I thought the same once I found this anser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221417/how-do-i-programmatically-access-the-target-path-of-a-windows-symbolic-link.   I'll wait for few days before marking it answer hoping someone has better suggestion.

Comment: The issue I faced might be due to permissions but my problem will be solved by using GetFinalPathNameByHandle(file,pathbuf,size,FILE_NAME_OPENED); API.